# Python to send a message to Teams using Microsoft Graph whilst keeping formatting with JSON vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive

Tags: python, json, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to send a message to MS Teams using MS Graph. This code works if I just use an unformatted string, like the below:

```
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    }
    body = {
        "body": {
            "content": message
        },
        "replyToId": message_id
    }
    response = requests.post(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{reply_to_id}/replies",
        headers=headers,
        json=body
    )
```

However if I adapt this code to send formatted text, it doesn't recognise the JSON payload.

```
def send_teams_message_alt(team_id, channel_id, message_id, message, bearer_token):
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}/replies"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"  #,
        # "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    adaptive_message = {"type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "body":         [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Hello world!",
            "size": "large",
            "weight": "bolder"
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is the output message in JSON format using vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive.",
            "wrap": True
          }
        ],
        "replyToId": message_id
    }
    print(json.dumps(adaptive_message))
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json.dumps(adaptive_message))

    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Adaptive Card message sent successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to send Adaptive Card message:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

print statement with the json code to be sent:

```
{"type": "AdaptiveCard", "body": [{"type": "TextBlock", "text": "Hello world!", "size": "large", "weight": "bolder"}, {"type": "TextBlock", "text": "This is the output message in JSON format using vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive.", "wrap": true}], "replyToId": "1696464791573"}
```

Error message:

```
Failed to send Adaptive Card message: 400 {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Empty Payload. JSON content expected.","innerError":{"date":"2023-10-05T10:36:10","request-id":"ad6d20b1-366f-4557-ac59-9afdc4fb7e90","client-request-id":"ad6d20b1-366f-4557-ac59-9afdc4fb7e90"}}}
```

Comment: `json=` takes a raw json, but you dump it to a string, that is not right. Try `json=adaptive_message`

Comment: If you were meant to dump it try using `data=json.dumps(adaptive_message)`